# Local overwrite of an executable is not working on mac os x

Tags: linux, macos

On mac os x, I'd like to be able to have arguments to `head` after the filename, like on ubuntu: `head <filename> -n 2`

So I have a `head` executable in `~/bin/head` and that's listed *before* `/usr/bin` in $PATH:

```
piousbox@mac:~/bin$ which head
/Users/piousbox/bin/head
```

The script is simple:

```
if [[ $# == 3 ]]; then
  /usr/bin/head $2 $3 $1
else
  /usr/bin/head $1
fi
```

But when I run `head <somefile> -n 2` it still gives me the errors

```
head: -n: No such file or directory
head: 2: No such file or directory
```

Suggesting that rather than my file, the system's `head` is being used. How do I fix that?

Comment: Add a proper shebang (like `#!/bin/bash`) as the first line of the script, and to debug add `set -x` after that to get an execution trace as it runs. BTW, this method will be very fragile, since it doesn't cope with passing multiple filenames (or no filenames, in which case `head` should read from stdin), if you use the standard `head -n 2 filename` it'll mess it up, it won't work with filenames with spaces, etc etc etc. And since it's in `PATH`, it'll also affect (and maybe break) any scripts you run that use `head` internally and expect normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have included in the PATH your folder as `~/bin/head`,
use instead `$HOME/bin/head`.